# Generic code or code easy to understand?

Tags: design, programming-practices

At work now I had an argument with co-worker, because I made a page that he feels is **too generic**.

The page has **3 modes** (simple, adv and special) - it has to work like this, because we don't choose how the specification is written. in each mode **the page looks different**(the changes are not big - **it shows/hides 5 text fields** in different combinations based on the mode).

My co-worker think it should be **3 pages** and when you change something you should just **merge** the changes to other two modes.

The fields now has code like `rendered="#{mode!=2}"`, etc.

P.S. Now the difference is 5 fields, but **in the future no1 know how much it will be changed**.

---

We use Seam(JSF/Facelets), here is pseudo facelet code(to make it easier to understand). I did not put it in panelGroups to better present the problem.

```
<h:output rendered="mode=2" value="Name: " />
<h:input rendered="mode=2" value="bean.name" />
<h:output rendered="mode=2" value="Surename: " />
<h:input rendered="mode=2" value="bean.surname"  />

<h:output rendered="mode!=2" value="Surename: " />
<h:input rendered="mode!=2" value="bean.surname"  />
<h:output rendered="mode!=2" value="#{mode==1?'My Name':'My friends name'}" />
<h:input rendered="mode!=2" value="bean.name" />
```

---

I duplicated version it would look like this(pseudo code)

```
<c:if test=mode=1>
        <ui:include view=modeSimple.xhtml>
</c:if>
<c:if test=mode=2>
        <ui:include view=modeAdv.xhtml>
</c:if>
<c:if test=mode=3>
        <ui:include view=modeSpec.xhtml>
</c:if>


modeSimple.xhtml
    <h:output value="Surename: " />
    <h:input value="bean.surname"  />
    <h:output value="My Name" />
    <h:input value="bean.name" />
modeAdv.xhtml
    <h:output value="Name: " />
    <h:input value="bean.name" />
    <h:output value="Surename: " />
    <h:input value="bean.surname"  />
modeSpec.xhtml
    <h:output value="Surename: " />
    <h:input value="bean.surname"  />
    <h:output value="My friends name" />
    <h:input value="bean.name" />
```

Comment: In your example, why not "<h:output rendered="mode!=2" value="bean.nameLabel" />"?

Comment: @Lenny222 you say I should not hardcode labels, but keep them with data? :| or do you meant to say I should use i18n? from your code I understand you want to output data, but this is a form with labels.

Comment: To me templates should rather be static. I have the impression that (business) logic is creeping into your templates. Since you use code (a Bean appaerantly) to handle logic anyway, i would consider dealing with business logic there, if possible.

Comment: The "code easy to understand" phrase may turn out to be incorrect.

Comment: @Lenny222 you think form should be static and submit no data? why use forms then? tables are for static data.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Its easy to understand for every web programmer, but if you program in Swing or C++ than its harder to understand how forms work.

Comment: @0101: I meant the form definition.

Comment: @Lenny222 The form is always defined like this "label:input". in HTML "Name:<input type="text"/>". in JSF "<h:outputText value="Name:" /><h:inputText value="#{bean.name}" />". As you can see I can't just use one control, because the labels must be hardcoded in template and can't be dynamic from database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should structure your templates using the same rules as when programming. This essentially means extracting common design elements into separate files to avoid duplication, and thus achieve more reusable design. That is rule #1 ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and the method is called refactoring in programming terms.

The second rule is that you should strive for simplicity and clarity. It should be easy to understand the layout and where to go when to you need to change things.

Following the first rule to the letter leads to heavy decomposition of your gui into lots and lots of small snippets which can make it hard to understand how the layout is created. You have to hunt around a lot to find where things are. This violates the second rule, so **you need to find a balance** between these two opposites.

But the best approach is to find a solution that avoids this issue completely. I think, in this case, you should **consider a simpler approach altogether**. I assume this is HTML and you mention "simple and advanced" states in the GUI. Have you considered *always* generating *all* fields and then handle the GUI logic in JavaScript? In other words, write client-side code which hides and shows the relevant fields on the fly depending on which mode (state) it is in?

This also has the benefit of being able to switch mode on demand without involving the server and you don't have to compromise any of the rules. Another great thing is that you can let the front-end guys do these changes without having to involve the back-end programmers who usually are not that overly keen on spending time tweaking and polishing the design and interaction.

Comment: I disagree that JS is simpler, why? most of my co-worker don't know JS and Java web frameworks more and more allow you to ignore JS(Richfaces, GWT). Almost all companies do not care about JS(I think I was asked one JS question in all companies I have ever interviewed in). So my co-workers would not touch that code and they would just re-write it if they had to change it. Your idea is good, but its not realistic. plus why keep part of your logic in java and part in JS? I think thats the reason why stored procedures had died(and I did like them).

Comment: @0101 I didn't say JS is simpler or harder than anything. It depends on your skills. With a competent html coder, this would not be problem. I said that by deferring GUI problems to the GUI layer (where it belongs), you often end up with a much simpler solution. This is because GUIs are *highly* dynamic and interactive, which language like JS is made for. Just because you think that "no companies care about JS", doesn't make my point any less valid.

Comment: I think its kind of does, the question is what to do in my situation and your answer is like "use stored procedures" and that is not valid since nobody is using it and it would be hard to understand why I would have used them. I'm asking which way is better for the future since I'm not 100% sure my choice is the best one(now the best way is to ignore annoying co-worker).

Comment: @0101: Working with web and HTML more or less implies JavaScript (and HTTP and CSS and images...), so you can't really blame me for assuming that JavaScript was an option. It's not like I'm asking you to write it in Swing.

Comment: I'm not blaming you, I'm just saying that in modern programming this is not really an option, its just my opinion. your idea is good, but it won't work for me.

Comment: @0101: Fair enough. Just note that *your* idea of what "modern programming" means differs a great deal from mine.

Comment: "Almost all companies do not care about JS" -- do you seriously believe that?  Rich interfaces on the web have been moving in a client-side direction for many years now.  I feel you are missing the boat on this one.

Comment: @Marcie, unless you are a hardcore web designer company, wouldn't you like client side Javascript to be something handled by a library?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I use a Javascript library.  But I also have to write a lot of Javascript myself to make sure there is a rich experience for every requirement.  Sometimes what you need just isn't in a library.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the code, I can only speculate, but I would guess that *at the moment* your code is "on the edge".

For 2 or 3 modes with a limited number of changes between those modes what you have now *is probably* OK. However, were it to be any more complicated then it sounds like it should be refactored into separate pages.

Personally I prefer easy to understand code - it's much more maintainable, both for other developers and yourself when you have to pick it up again 6 months down the line.

However, there's no sense in refactoring the code *now* to solve a problem which might not exist in the future. You say you don't know how much the requirements will change - and that includes no change - so applying YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It) don't do anything now.

Mark the code as requiring attention in the future so you don't forget it, but don't change (and potentially break) it now.

Comment: +1 - If in doubt go with easy to understand.  The nag at the back of your mind about whether you should make it generic is natures way of telling you that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I've done pretty much the same thing. Believe me, after implementing few different behaviours for each mode, the "main page" becomes a mess nearly impossible to read. You would then see only a bunch of control flow blocks (shortly followed by Matrix digital rain). I found myself removing some blocks just to get a clear view of what's inside a certain mode.

So the "separate pages" is the way to go. However when you do that, you have to "fight" code duplication problem. This is where your collegue might be wrong by suggesting merges. Sadly so I've done that also. Basically it works, but it consumes a lot of precious time and eventually by poor merge "common area" of the pages is out of sync and merging becomes a real nightmare. So you are right in objecting a merge as a reasonable solution.

As you can see from many responses, the correct approach is to extract truly "common" parts to external entities (JSP page fragments, JSF snippets, whatever) and include them in those pages.

Comment: the real problem that common code is just the controls h:inputText+h:outputText for single field. I feel its not worth to fight it. plus this page might die since its not really functional, because of the modes and its confusing even to other developers(from user point of view).

Comment: So the problem is really when to do the transition. You have to reconsider splitting after every modification. When the page starts to be messy -- split it. I think your co-worker will also be more comfortable if you consider his idea good, but not yet worth implementing.

Answer (score 2):

Duplication of code is practically never a good thing. That said, a small amount duplicated not many more than twice is acceptable in real life - it is better to be pragmatic than religious about it. In your case, it sounds like a larger amount of code and 3 places, so it's slightly over my personal threshold. Thus I lean towards the generic version. And at any rate, if it works now, there is no need to touch it just for theoretical reasons.

OTOH when you say that there can be more differences between the pages in the future, this might mean that at some point in time it becomes more economic to switch to separate pages (while striving to minimize duplication between them by extracting commonalities as much as possible). So reevaluate the situation before each future change.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JSF.  Each rendered="..." essentially means you have an if in your code, which cause additional complexity.

I've done the same thing because "it is the same page just with a few differences here and there" and put very simply, it **doesn't work** in the long run because it *isn't* the same page and you will need to do more and more elaborate tricks to make it work properly causing it to be needlessly hard to maintain.

If you use JSF with facelets instead of JSP (which you should if you could) then you can build XML-fragments corresponding to a block of the page, which you can then include where needed.  This will buy you modularity and still allow you to reuse content across pages.

Listen to your co-worker.  He is right.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @0101, I suspected exactly this.  Don't do it, it is the road to madness - most likely for you - and certainly for future maintainers.

Comment: the real problem is that my way is the best way. if i did 3 pages than someone could change just one of the pages and do not think about the others. I would like my version as a future maintainer.

Comment: I think my code is making the future maintaine think about other cases. If you were a new programmer to the project and in debugger found that you need to change code in baseFormBasic.xhtml, would you also change it in baseFormAdv and baseFormSpec?

Comment: @0101, your way is not the necessarily the best way - please do not have preconceived opinions when asking such a question. Regarding "only change one page" - that was why I suggested creating JSF-snippets as building blocks which are then included on each page using it.  See the <ui:include> tag.

Comment: can you show in pseudo code how you would do it(change my pseudo code - maybe you could edit your answer?). because i feel your way is more complex and i really don't gain that much. i think you meant that i should create something like taglibs for every input/output pair(it sounds like good idea, but its a lot of work and like some ChrisF I might not need to change it ever, so why waste time now?).

Comment: @0101, please look up the usage and semantics of the <ui:include> tag.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I won't since I already know that, but thx for suggestion.

Comment: @0101, why ask what is best, if you just want to have your preconceived opinion confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance to generate the page using code?
In this case, how about something like:

```
page1 = {
   showField1 = true;
   showField2 = false;
   showField3 = true;
  }
page2 = {
   showField1 = true;
   showField2 = false;
   showField3 = false;
  }
```

And in the page rendering code

```
if page.showField1 then ....
if page.showField2 then ....
```

Or in OOP-style:

```
class Page1 {
   renderField1() { ...}
   renderField2() {}
   renderField2() { ...}
}
class Page2 {
   renderField1() { ...}
   renderField2() {}
   renderField2() {}
}
```

Comment: no, there is no change. I would be crucified if I did it. plus it creates exacly the same problem. if == rendered.

Comment: It is not the exact problem since it extracts the page-logic. Doing only one task, instead of two.

Comment: maybe, but i feel its the same. my reason is that showing fields is only one thing that is different, there is also different placement and sometimes labels. plus its the web programming, so I can't do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

modal code *can only get worse*. Classify and decide once at the start, and branch to clean implementations without modes.

Comment: isn't code duplication worst? all the code should always be synchronize with each other(if you change simple, remember to change advance and what if you forget?)

Comment: isolate the common code in subroutines, functions, helper/base classes, et al; in OOP, modal code is an indication of missing classes...

Answer (score 0):

The essence of this question seems to be: when you have three very similar web pages with a few minor differences, is it better to duplicate those three pages and modify each as needed, or build into a single page the logic to dynamically render the page according to which "mode" is being viewed.

For the record, I am a JSF guy and I like it, and I make use of conditional rendering.

If you opt to have three pages, there is risk that as changes happen the maintainer may not apply that correctly to all three pages.

If you opt for using conditional rendering, you solve that problem but you have moved some business logic into your page which might need some thought.

I personally would have no problem with the use of conditional rendering, but would really like to see the mode logic moved to a backing bean, e.g: instead of:

`<h:output rendered="mode=2" value="Name: " />`

I like:

`<h:output rendered="#{myBean.advancedMode}" value="Name: " />`

Where the bean handles the logic and returns true or false to control the rendering of the element.

The reason is the mode being viewed may need to control more than just this one page, may need to persist it beyond even the user's single session, or you may need to change the modes completely down the road.

Or, you can accept that either approach has potential downsides, and all the downsides seem to be regarding easing pains down the road, and agree to  worry about it further when one of those "down the road" things actually come up, and then make a better decisions now that more is actually known about how the requirements might change.